# react-native send crash report with stack trace to my server

Tags: react-native, crash-reports

I'm building a mobile app for both android and IOS by react-native. Now I want to sent crash report with stack trace + client's info to my server (by restful api). **How can I catch error which I can not handle (make app crash**).

I have checked crashlytics, but it can not send log to my server.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend crashlytics despite you mentioned it. I am using it for some time now and it works great. It is worth to mention that you won't receive any logs if your app isn't built in release mode (on android).

Comment: Hi nehvaleem, my company don't allow to upload log to the third party, we want log will be uploaded to our server. can crashlytics do this?